# Was Matt Damon’s role in Thor: Ragnarok purely due to his role in Dogma?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In one of the beginning scenes in *Thor: Ragnarok* we see a play portraying the actions of the previous movies. The actors are Sam Neill, Luke Hemsworth, and Matt Damon (uncredited).

The casting of Luke was obviously a joke of getting Chris brother, but was Matt Damon’s role of play-Loki a reference to *Dogma*, where he plays a fallen angel named Loki?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's possible but it's more likely because Matt Damon and Chris Hemsworth are friends.

Kevin Feige explained...

> “There was an idea in the script phase. I don’t remember if it was our writer, Eric Pearson’s or if it was Taika [Waititi]’s or if it was our executive producer, Brad Winderbaum to bring the audience up to speed on the fact that everybody thinks Loki is dead. So that when it was revealed that he was Odin, it would make some semblance of sense to people who weren’t following along from all the films. There was this idea to do it in this funny sort of stage play which Loki/Odin had put on to celebrate himself. We then watched whatever was the season before last Game of Thrones. They did a similar thing where they had a stage play with some events from other episodes, not that we were like, “Oh crap.” But then it’s different enough.
>
> There was a fun idea of “Let’s get Luke Hemsworth to play Thor,” Taika had worked with Sam Neill in Hunt for the Wilderpeople. He was willing to come in and do Odin. So who could be Loki? Who could be Loki? Who could be Loki? We didn’t have any brilliant ideas. At one point, off handedly, Mr. Hemsworth goes, **“Well what if I ask my friend Matt?” I said, “Matt who?” He said, “My friend, Matt Damon.” “Okay. Sure. Sure Chris, ask your friend Matt Damon. He’s not doing this. Oh he’s gonna do it. He’s flying down.” The next thing I know, Matt Damon is on set in a full Loki costume, full Loki wig.** We have pictures that maybe we’ll share some day of Tom Hiddleston in a full Loki outfit standing next to Matt Damon in full Loki outfit. It is very surreal and very amazing. What a testament to, I just met him for the first time, I wasn’t there when he shot this. I just met him for the first time last night. What an awesome thing, for him to come down here for his friend. It was purely based on his friendship with Hemsworth that he came and did this.”
>
> <sup>[Source](http://collider.com/thor-ragnarok-matt-damon-cameo-explained-kevin-feige/)</sup>

Comment: Wow, didn't know this. Matt Damon, what a guy.